# Creating iOS Framework

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks

I was trying to create an iOS `Framework` using [This Guide](http://www.blackjaguarstudios.com/blog/programming/2012/11/22/xcode-45-creating-ios-framework-and-hold-my-hand-im-3-years-old). I did all the things in the same way as mentioned in the tutorial but now when I'm trying to use that Framework into my sample project, I'm getting the following error.

```
Ld /Users/Ankur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestingFramework-eaowfdnjkurezghccwfwtnmftxig/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestingFramework.app/TestingFramework normal i386
cd /Users/Ankur/Desktop/TestingFramework
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/Ankur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestingFramework-eaowfdnjkurezghccwfwtnmftxig/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Ankur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestingFramework-eaowfdnjkurezghccwfwtnmftxig/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Ankur/Desktop/TestingFramework/../Test/Products -filelist /Users/Ankur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestingFramework-eaowfdnjkurezghccwfwtnmftxig/Build/Intermediates/TestingFramework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestingFramework.build/Objects-normal/i386/TestingFramework.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework TestFramework -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/Ankur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestingFramework-eaowfdnjkurezghccwfwtnmftxig/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestingFramework.app/TestingFramework

duplicate symbol _NXArgc in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o
/Users/Ankur/Desktop/Test/Products/TestFramework.framework/TestFramework
duplicate symbol _NXArgv in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o
/Users/Ankur/Desktop/Test/Products/TestFramework.framework/TestFramework
duplicate symbol ___progname in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o
/Users/Ankur/Desktop/Test/Products/TestFramework.framework/TestFramework
duplicate symbol _environ in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o
/Users/Ankur/Desktop/Test/Products/TestFramework.framework/TestFramework
duplicate symbol start in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o
/Users/Ankur/Desktop/Test/Products/TestFramework.framework/TestFramework
ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Remove your TestFramework.framework from your project, and when you readd it, don't copy it over and reference it instead of making a copy. Or just remove it and see if it works.

Comment: Tried both, didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps using #include instead of #import somewhere?

The end result of the problem is that you including this file twice somewhere

http://iphone-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/csu/crt.c